# Concatenating PHP in img src with echo $_GET function

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, echo

I believe i have a syntax error here and would appreciate any help resolving...

I am trying to modify the img src of a woocommerce image placeholder using the $_GET function so that it echo's the variable [/'thumb/'] in the url via php.

The example URL is:
http://asharkey.com/product/limited-edition-print/?title=20090629-DSC_2131.jpg&thumb=galleries/portfolio/images/20090629-DSC_2131.jpg&image_title=Kenyan%20Dance

The template file that i am editing is product-image.php, specifically line 54:
$html .= sprintf( '

which i have modified to:

```html
  if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
   $html  = '<div data-thumb="' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'shop_thumbnail' ) . '" class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image"><a href="' . esc_url( $full_size_image[0] ) . '">';
   $html .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'shop_single', $attributes );
   $html .= '</a></div>';
  } else {
   $html  = '<div class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image--placeholder">';
   $html .= sprintf( '<img src="http://asharkey.com/<?php echo $_GET[\'thumb\']; ?>" alt="%s" class="wp-post-image" />', esc_url( wc_placeholder_img_src() ), esc_html__( 'Awaiting product image', 'woocommerce' ) );
   $html .= '</div>';
  }

  echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html', $html, get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) );

  do_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails' );
  ?>
```

Comment: `$html .= sprintf( '<img src="http://asharkey.com/%s" alt="%s" class="wp-post-image" />', $_GET['thumb'].esc_url( wc_placeholder_img_src() ), esc_html__( 'Awaiting product image', 'woocommerce' ) );`

Comment: Thanks for this code.  It was almost perfect except for one thing, i replaced the following:  .esc_url with a , esc_url

Answer (score 0):

ccKep's comment was almost correct, accept for one punctuation mark...  below is the correct code:

```
$html .= sprintf( '<img src="http://asharkey.com/%s" alt="%s" class="wp-post-image" />', $_GET['thumb'], esc_url( wc_placeholder_img_src() ), esc_html__( 'Awaiting product image', 'woocommerce' ) );
```

Thanks!